# Dynamic Tiled Display

Tags: css

I'm a bit of a CSS noob and I was hoping someone here would have the patience to point out the error of my ways.

Basically, I'm creating a mobile web platform and I'm designing a concept "landing page" which will consist of four equally sized rectangular (square on some resolutions) tiles (inspiration drawn from here: http://tinyurl.com/beartss).

Obviously with this application being mobile orientated I've been avoiding fixed widths and heights but can't quite get the same layout as seen in the image I linked. My HTML is laid out as follows:

```
        <div class="page-container">
            <div class="tile-1"></div>
            <div class="tile-2"></div>
            <div class="tile-3"></div>
            <div class="tile-4"></div>
        </div>
```

And the current CSS I'm using is...

```
html, body, .container 
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.page-container 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 99%;
    min-height: 99%;
    width: 99%;
}

.tile-1 
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 48%;
    width: 48%;
}

.tile-2 
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 48%;
    width: 48%;
}

.tile-3 
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 48%;
    width: 48%;
}

.tile-4 
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 48%;
    width: 48%;
}
```

This isn't even remotely near what I'm trying to achieve, and I've come by a rumour that percentage based height is never a good idea, either way, the above CSS gives me this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmBGP.png

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure I've just missed something with the height.

Comment: Do you want there to be a gap between the tiles?

Comment: A couple of pixel gap preferably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, block level elements won't appear on the same line as another block level element.  So, you need to either float them or change their display to something like inline-block.

http://jsfiddle.net/kyyjg/

You will find that mixing px on your borders with percentages for your dimensions to cause your elements to not take up the right amount of space because of how the box-model works.  You might find that adding `box-sizing: border-box` helpful.

If you're interested in another approach, here's how one might do it using flexbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/LJMdx/4/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.page-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1%;
}

.page-container div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 48%;
    flex: 1 1 48%;
    margin: 1%; /* optional */
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

If you don't want the gaps between the tiles, drop the 1% margin and padding: http://jsfiddle.net/LJMdx/3/

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but using your JS fiddle, I get the following in Chrome 23, http://i.imgur.com/ijlJ7Ke.png did I miss something?

Comment: Hm, I tested it in Chrome 24, where it appears as it should (taking up the entire vertical space of the fiddle).

Comment: Weird, I'm in Chrome 24 too and the Fiddle looks fine, just to be clear, this is when I run my page from VS2012 and it opens in Chrome, that's when I see that picture.

Comment: To be clearer, it isn't taking up the vertical space it should when I place it in an actual page outside of the fiddle.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't make any sense at all.  The body and html elements are as tall as they should be, but `.page-container` element won't grow.  It isn't a good fix, but adding these to `.page-container` will do it: `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `float:left`. [Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/8gtrpek4) -> is that the solution that your looking for?.

Added a `min-width` on each the tiles so that the template is the same on any resolution.